# How to create table with multiple columns with rows in titanium?

Tags: titanium-alloy

I am beginner to titanium i would like to create table with multiple column with rows like as html please, any one assist me. thank's in advance .

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use [Views](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View) instead of a table - you can compare them to Divs in Html.